# INSERT SET :id if row does not exist, UPDATE WHERE :id otherwise

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code which creates a row in database with a specified id if it does not exist and updates that row otherwise. It is a little bit slow (it checks if a row exists and then inserts/updates it) and I want to optimize it. How can I consolidate the whole thing into one SQL query? I think I should use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but I do not understand how it works. Thank you.

```
$objectExists = true;
try {
    $object = new Object();
    $object->loadFromDatabaseById($this->id, $dbh); // tries to load object from database, throws
                                         // ExceptionNotFound if object with specified id does not exist
}
catch(ExceptionNotFound $e) {
    $objectExists = false;
}

if($objectExists)
    $sth = $dbh->prepare(
        'UPDATE objects ' .
        'SET property1 = :property1, ' .
            'property2 = :property2, ' .
            'property3 = :property3 ' .
        'WHERE id = :id'
    );
else
    $sth = $dbh->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO objects ' .
        'SET id = :id, ' .
            'property1 = :property1, ' .
            'property2 = :property2, ' .
            'property3 = :property3'
    );
$sth->bindParam(':id', $this->id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':property1', $this->property1, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':property2', $this->property2, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':property3', $this->property3, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$this->id = (int)$this->id;
```

Comment: The technical term is "upsert" by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL has a `REPLACE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) that does exactly what you’re looking for:

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

An alternative without deletion would be the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If you specify `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`, MySQL performs an `UPDATE` of the old row.

Comment: Don't' use REPLACE, it will hurt performance even more. The "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" fits better.

Comment: Thank you, Dovyski - I will use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE instead.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `id` is either a Primary Key or Unique Key/Index, you can shorten it to something like -

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO objects ( id, property1, property2, property3) ' .
    'VALUES ( :id,:property1,:property2,:property3) '. 
    'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' .
        'property1 = :property1, ' .
        'property2 = :property2, ' .
        'property3 = :property3 '
);
$sth->bindParam(':id', $this->id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':property1', $this->property1, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':property2', $this->property2, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':property3', $this->property3, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$this->id = (int)$this->id;
```